# How to fetch a row along with its one to many relations with the mysql crate?

Tags: mysql, rust

I am able to fetch a single model:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
extern crate mysql;
#[macro_use]
extern crate nickel;

use nickel::{Nickel, NickelError, Request, HttpRouter, Action, Middleware, MiddlewareResult};
use nickel::mimes::MediaType;
use nickel::status::*;
use rustc_serialize::json;
use mysql as my;

#[derive(RustcEncodable , RustcDecodable, Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct User {
    id: i32,
    username: Option<String>,
    email: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(RustcEncodable , RustcDecodable)]
struct Car {
    id: i32,
    car_name: Option<String>,
    car_number: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(RustcEncodable , RustcDecodable)]
struct UserInfo {
    info: User,
    cars: Vec<Car>,
}
fn main() {
    server.get("/users",
               middleware! { |request, mut response|


    let pool = my::Pool::new("mysql://USERID:PASSWORD@localhost:3306/DBNAME").unwrap();

    let users: Vec<User> = pool.prep_exec("SELECT id, username, email FROM users limit 10", ())
      .map(|result| {
        result.map(|x| x.unwrap()).map(|row| {
          let (id, username, email) = my::from_row(row);
            User {
              id: id,
              username: username,
              email: email
            }
          }).collect()
        }).unwrap();


    let user_data = json::encode(&users).unwrap();


    let mut data_result = "{\"data\": ".to_owned();
    data_result.push_str(&user_data.to_string());

    data_result.push_str("}");

    response.set(StatusCode::Ok);
    response.set(MediaType::Json);

    format!("{}", data_result)

      });
    server.listen("127.0.0.1:6767");
}
```

A user has many cars, a one-to-many relationship. I want to fetch a user's info along with the cars:

```
{username: name, car:[{ car_name: first}, {car_name: second} ...]}
```

How to fetch both user and car data?